# LINQPad / LINQ To SQL - Simple Query Throws Out of Memory Only When Executed Inside a Loop

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, locking, linqpad

I have a database with following relationship:

Calculations -< BinaryData

I need to loop all the calculations and then query associated BinaryData rows.  The query for BinaryData is a simple where clause on the BinaryData.bdCalculationKey.  Running this query immediately returns when it is ran standalone, but when running it inside the looping of Calculations it throws out of memory exception.  The code looks like this:

```
var groupName = "NYPH";
var serverName = "192.168.100.132";

var tahitiDB = 
    new BTR.Evolution.Data.DataContexts.Legacy.Profile.BtrProfile( 
        BTR.Evolution.Core.Registry.ProfileDatabase( groupName, serverName ) 
    ) { ObjectTrackingEnabled = false, DeferredLoadingEnabled = false, CommandTimeout = 30 };

var data = tahitiDB.Calculations.Where(c => c.Profile.Client.cName == groupName && !c.calcIsFailed);

data.Count().Dump();

tahitiDB.BinaryDatas
        .Where(b => b.bdCalculationKey == new Guid( "3d53aa12-0353-e911-83b4-005056b9729f" ) )
        .Dump();

foreach( var p in data )
{
    p.calcKey.Dump();
    tahitiDB.BinaryDatas
            .Where(b => b.bdCalculationKey == p.calcKey )
            .Select(b => new { b.bdKey, b.bdCalculationKey, b.bdFilename, b.bdDateCreated })
            .Dump();

    break;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of LINQPad result (also shows a successful dump of the query **outside** the loop):

[image]

*Update*: I assume the close vote is because of requested information from comment.  Full code listed above.  Not sure what else there is to say about tahitiDB.  It is simply a compiled L2S `DataContext`.  If needed, I can post the 1000's of lines of generated code.  As for `Calculations` and `BinaryData` tables, both tables have Guid primary keys.  Calculations has create/update timestamps, couple 'bit/boolean' flags about status, few Guid foreign keys, and two Xml blob columns to store inputs and data for calculation.  BinaryData has create/update timestamps, few 'text' fields for name/type of binary data, few Guid foreign keys (based on who owns the binary data) and a 'Binary' content field for actual cached document.

Comment: What type is p.CalcKey? If not a Guid, does it make any difference if you convert it to a Guid inside the loop and pass that variable to the linq query?

Comment: It is of type Guid/uniqueidentifier.

Comment: Strange. What is the SQL Generated? I don't understand your screenshot. From the results, you seem to have dumped p.calcKey and then executed the query and it has found and dumped no items and then thrown the error (even though the break indicates there is nothing more to do. Is this consistent even if you restart LinqPad?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're not making updates, you should disable object tracking to avoid keeping all the database objects in memory:

```
this.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: I did assign that to tahitiDB on line 7.